# SAP pegar o valor text

Tags: vbs, vbscript, erp

Bom dia, estou com um problema, espero que alguem possa me ajudar.

Tenho uma tabela no SAP.

Preciso capturar o valor da coluna Qtd.Pç

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

pela gravação do sap script trouxe essa linha

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlALV_RECEBE/shellcont/shell").setCurrentCell 0,"QTDPEC"
```

0 = 1º linha
"QTDPEC" = nome da coluna

Tentei colocar

```
x = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlALV_RECEBE/shellcont/shell").setCurrentCell 0,"QTDPEC".text
```

msgbox = x
Da erro

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlALV_RECEBE/shellcont/shell").text
```

msgbox = x
Da erro

Não retorna nenhum valor.

Answer (score 2):

Use: `getcellvalue`

Ficaria assim:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlALV_RECEBE/shellcont/shell").getcellvalue(0,"QTDPEC")
```

Até.

Comment: Eu uso esse getcellvalue quando é tabela. o resto uso .text mesmo